# Is there a limit to how early one can apply for a Visa in the United States?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, h1b-visas

As per [USTravelDocs.com](http://www.ustraveldocs.com/in/in-gen-faq.asp#qlistfandm) you cannot apply for the F-1 Visa 120 days before the expected starting date on the I-20.

Is there some similar condition for the H1B Visa or the B1/B2 Visa as well?

Answer (score 2):

For the H1B visa, from [USTravelDocs](http://www.ustraveldocs.com/in/in-gen-faq.asp#qlistwork10):

> You can apply for an H1B visa up to 90 days before the petition start
>   date listed on the form I-797, Notice of Action. However, you cannot
>   enter the US earlier than 10 days prior to the start date listed on
>   the I-797 unless you are already working on an H1B visa for the same
>   petitioner.

For the B1/B2, there's no real restriction as far as I can find, the only recommendation is that you apply [no later than 60 days before the date of travel](http://www.immihelp.com/business-visa/) to ensure that it gets processed in time.  Indeed the USCIS pages on [B1 visas](http://www.rapidimmigration.com/1_eng_info_b1business.html) and [B2 visas](http://www.rapidimmigration.com/1_eng_info_b2tourist.html) mention no requirement for when you can apply.

Comment: As far as I understand those are both restrictions on how late I can apply, not how early I can apply right?

Comment: Did you check the link? It's specifically under the heading "How early can I apply".
For the second one, as I said, there's no limit mentioned anywhere on how early, but clarified that there is a limit on how late.

Comment: Maybe I've been constantly failing at English when reading that sentence earlier :/ I checked the link earlier also, what I understood was that I couldn't apply for an H1B any later that T-90 days from my petition start date. So what it actually means is that I can *start applying* T-90 days *before* my actual petition start date? Giving me effectively 90 days to apply/wait?

Comment: Mark, check this link - http://www.immihelp.com/visas/h1b/visa-stamping-faq.html. This seems to disagree with the language in the above link. :(

Comment: What part? The bit I see says "You can apply at any time up to 90 days in advance of the employment start date, as shown on the I-797 notice.
However, you can only enter the U.S. 10 days in advance of the employment start date, unless you are already working on an H1B
visa and have applied for restamping." which would match what it says in the above link...

Comment: @Doc you're likely to know about this - any chance you can help out?

Comment: Yeah, so basically I can apply *upto* 90 days in advance i.e on the 89th day I cannot apply anymore and I'm late. BUT/"However" on the contrary I can enter the US *only 10 days in advance* of the employment start date i.e 11 days before I'm *not allowed* to enter but 10 days before I am *allowed* to enter.